# I'm trying to pull results from a database and pragmatically select the results in a chain-select box that has it's results pulled from a database

Tags: php, jquery

I have a chain select box which fills from a database.

What I want to do is pragmatically select a result from the first box, 
wait for the second select box to be populated from the DB then select a result in that and then a third and fourth select box.

this is a JSfiddle with the layout, minus the DB data: http://jsfiddle.net/dDQsQ/1/

If I try

```
locationselect = JHarray['location'];
$('select#locationselect').val(locationselect).trigger('change');

departmentselect = JHarray['department'];
$('select#departmentselect').val(departmentselect).trigger('change');
```

it does not allow enough time for the second chain select box to populate.

How might I go about waiting for it to populate?

Thanks guys/gals.

Answer (score 0):

How about setting an onchange event handler to the very last select (which will fire when the selected value changes) and create your function there?